# ColdFusion String to Hex to SHA-2 - Not Encrypting Properly

Tags: php, encryption, hash, coldfusion

I have a simple web form hosted on CF 8 that posts to an off-server payment processing website. The payment processor requires that a number of values be encrypted and placed in a hidden field to validate me as a user. In their documentation they show how this is done in PHP, ASP, and JSP.

**Their PHP Example**

```
    function createHash($chargetotal) { 
      global $storename, $sharedSecret; 
      $str = $storename . getDateTime() . $chargetotal . $sharedSecret;
      for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $hex_str.=dechex(ord($str[$i])); 
      }
      return hash('sha256', $hex_str);
    }

    <input type='hidden' value='<? $hash=createHash(80.00); echo "$hash"; ?>'>
```

**My ColdFusion**

```
    txndatetime = DateFormat(now(),'yyyy:mm:dd') & '-' & DateFormat(now(),'HH:mm:ss');

    function createHash( chargetotal, txndatetime ) {
      var str = application.storename & txndatetime & chargetotal & application.sharedsecret;
      var hex_str = binaryEncode( charsetDecode( str, "utf-8" ), "hex" ) ;
      return hash( hex_str, "SHA-256" );
    }

    <input type='hidden' value='#createHash(80.00,txndatetime)#'>
```

Can anyone spot any obvious differences? My hash is never the same as what the payment site expects. I would be amazed (sort of) if CF's hash function produced different results as the PHP hash function...Perhaps I got the "convert to hex" step wrong? Maybe my date is formatted differently than getDateTime in PHP?

I'd love if I had a PHP server to test, but I don't at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do this in PHP:

```
echo hash("sha256", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor");
```

I get

```
1c3f958abd85c54905c97fe8e0628fe76495711962a27daae34033781486da00
```

and this in CF:

```
hash("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor", "SHA-256" )
```

I get

```
1C3F958ABD85C54905C97FE8E0628FE76495711962A27DAAE34033781486DA00
```

Spot the difference?  Is your payment provider doing a case-sensitive check?  If not, then it must be a problem with how you're building up your string that you end up hashing.

The PHP example takes a string, loops over it, gets the ASCII decimal value of each character, converts it to hexadecimal.

Your CF version takes a string, converts the whole thing to binary, then to hexadecimal.  Why not just use the same method?  When I do this in CF I get the same values of the string that ends up being hashed:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= len(str); i++) {
     hex_str &= formatBaseN(asc(mid(str, i, 1)), 16);
}
```

Comment: Just as you were posting this I came to the same conclusion. After sticking an lcase() around the whole hash, it worked. THanks!

Comment: BTW converting to binary, then to hex was just the shortest way I know to write it .. but I did previously try to loop in the same way as the PHP example. The output of both methods was the same.

Comment: ok cool. I'm in the early stages of learning PHP from CF experience, and so far I'm just trying to do straight conversions of the functions and so on